# Tracking Click Events on Parent and Child DIV using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have close to 100 Bootstrap Cards (with Card Header and Card Body). The text in the Card Header needs to be tracked. I have used "Click Classes" to track all the Click events that happens on Card Header as they are unique.

As each card Body have description that varies, is there any way to trigger Click Event on Card Body and Capture Card header' text?

Answer (score 0):

you might use some Custom Javascript variable that looks into parent element of `{{Click Element}}` and then traverse down to Card Header and return its content. Some very vague draft could look like that:

```
function () {
  var baseElement = {{Click Elemnt}}
  var card = baseElement
  do {
    card = card.parentElemt
    if (card.matches('body')) {
      return null
    }
  } while (!card.matches('all.cards.selector'))
  var header = card.querySelector('some.header.selector')
  return header && header.innerText
}
```